# How can you dynamically import modules instead of hard-coding import in python?

Tags: python

I am currently working on transfer learning in deep learning. My task is to find out the weights of each model in tf.keras.applications. (Xception, VGG16, Vgg19, ResNet50, etc)

So, for now I have the following codes:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import *

model = Xception()
model.trainable = True

model.summary()
print(len(model.weights))
print(len(model.trainable_weights))
```

For the task, I have changed the model (e.g. VGG16, VGG19, ResNet50 so forth) and ran to see the results. Then, I manually copied and pasted the results on some other txt file like the following:

```
### trainable = True
# Xception  VGG16     VGG19
# 236       32        38
# 156       32        38

# ResNet50  ResNet101   ResNet152   ResNet50V2  ResNet101V2 ResNet152V2
# 320       626         932         272         544         816
# 214       418         622         174         344         514

# InceptionV3   InceptionResNetV2   MobileNet   MobileNetV2 
# 378           898                 137         262         
# 190           490                 83          158         

# DenseNet121   DenseNet169 DenseNet201 
# 606           846         1006        
# 364           508         604         

# NASNetLarge   NASNetMobile
# 1546          1126
# 1018          742

# EfficientNetB0    B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7
# 314               442 442 499 613 741 855 1040
# 213               301 301 340 418 506 584 711
```

But it seems to me that there is a way to do the whole process without having to change the model and run every single time. I tried out the following code:

```
import importlib
from tensorflow.keras import applications as ap

tmp = dir(ap)[-14:]
tmp.pop(2)
print(tmp)
# ['densenet', 'efficientnet', 'inception_resnet_v2', 'inception_v3', 'mobilenet', 'mobilenet_v2', 'nasnet', 'resnet', 'resnet50', 'resnet_v2', 'vgg16', 'vgg19', 'xception']    
MODULE_NAME = tmp
importlib.import_module(MODULE_NAME[0], package='../Users/ai/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/applications/')
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Study\keras2\temp_dynamic_import2.py", line 12, in <module>
    importlib.import_module(MODULE_NAME[0], package='../Users/ai/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/applications/')
  File "C:\Users\ai\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'densenet'
```

I was hoping to get a list of modules, and make a for loop to do the task. The following is a pseudo-code that I had in my mind:

```
module_list = importlib.import_modules[modules]
for module in module_list:
     model = module
     model.trainable = True
     print(model)
     print(len(model.weights))
     print(len(model.trainable_weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is using 'getattr' to get the sub-model of applications.

From "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/keras/applications/__ init__.py"

```
...
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB0
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB1
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB2
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.xception import Xception
...
```

from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.xception import Xception

for example:

```
model_name = "EfficientNetB5"
if model_name.startswith('EfficientNetB'):
    backbone = getattr(importlib.import_module("tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet"), model_name)       
if model_name.startswith('Xception'):
    backbone = getattr(importlib.import_module("tensorflow.keras.applications.xception"), model_name)       


base_model = backbone(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", 
input_shape=(240,240,3))
            
base_model.trainable = False
b_m_output = base_model(inputs, training=False)
gap2d = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(b_m_output)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(top_dropout_rate)(gap2d)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(outputnum)(dropout)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name=model_name)
            
model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss=ed_metric_2d_mean)
```